# Software License Web Application

Tags: web-applications, licensing

We are in the process of building a web application for a client and they have inquired about owning the code for the site. We would like to issue a license agreement to the client for use of the code if we for any reason we are no longer working on the project.  We would like to have ownership of the code but allow them use wherever they see fit, the only limitation we would like to have is the sale of the code.  The are a company with several employees and will only be using the application within their company.

Thanks in advance

-JN

Comment: You should ask this question here instead: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If there's even a question here, it's likely more of a question for an attorney than a software developer.  Attorneys usually cost money, of course, but that's a measure of what legal control over the code is worth to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need an attorney.  Try this: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=software+licensing+attorney

Comment: This is probably the route we will end up going if we cannot draft an amendment to our current contract. Thanks all for the input. It was very helpful.